# Change branding logo in Firefox

Tags: firefox, build, branding

I have created a running local build of Firefox 31.2esr on my computer. Now I want to change the branding logo of Firefox with my own logo. How can I do that?

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it worked in 31.2esr, but in modern versions of Firefox (Nightly 56.0a1 / Linux) that could be done by changing PNG files in a directory `./browser/chrome/icons/default/` (although it changes taskbar and window title bar icons but not the logo in the About dialog).